# Check Column H for specific value and delete cell based on a different value and loop

Tags: excel, vba

I need to search down Column H and find all instances of "AA". If "AA" exists I then need to check a cell which resides two rows below and left seven cells (which is column A). This cell may or may not have a value of "--". If it does have a value of "--" then delete that cell and continue checking down column A. Deleting all cells with "--" until it reaches a blank cell. At which point it continues down Column H to look for more of the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have amended the code as described in Points 1 to 3 (see comments).  I hope the new code does exactly what you require.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteUnderScoreRows()

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLastAA As Long

  ' Add a quote to the beginning of the statement if you
  ' want to watch the rows disppear
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  RowLastAA = 0
  RowCrnt = Rows.Count      ' Start search from row 1

  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Do While True
      ' * Find next row after RowCrnt that contains "AA" in column H
      ' * The first parameter of Find is the string to be searched for.
      ' * The second parameter is the cell from which the search is to
      '   start.
      ' * The last parameter I have used is the direction of the search.
      '   I have used xlNext meaning down or right.  xlPrevious means
      '   up or left.
      ' * Find does not look at the start cell.  It starts at the next
      '   cell in the chosen direction.  It continues until it finds the
      '   required string or until it reaches the bottom or top when it
      '   wraps.  I have intialised RowCrnt (the start row) to the bottom
      '   row so the search start from the next row in the chosen
      '   direction which is 1.
      Set Rng = .Columns("H").Find("AA", .Cells(RowCrnt, "H"), _
                                    xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext)
      If Rng Is Nothing Then
        ' No AAs found
        Exit Sub
      End If
      RowCrnt = Rng.Row
      If RowCrnt <= RowLastAA Then
        ' Find wraps so when it reaches the bottom it starts again at
        ' the top.  I have recorded the row of the last AA found in
        ' RowLastAA.  If RowCrnt = RowLastAA, Excel has wrapped to the
        ' only AA in the sheet.  If RowCrnt < RowLastAA, there are two
        ' or more AAs and Excel has wrapped to the first one.
        Exit Sub
      End If
      'Loop deleting underscore rows until find a non-underscore row
      Do While .Cells(RowCrnt + 2, 1).Value = "'-" Or _
               .Cells(RowCrnt + 2, 1).Value = "-"
        .Cells(RowCrnt + 2, 1).EntireRow.Delete
      Loop
      RowLastAA = RowCrnt   ' Record this AA row so can detect loop
    Loop
  End With


  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that I know VBA, and do not intend to display myself as something that I'm not. But I'm trying to learn and hope to be as good as you someday soon, becuase this code ROCKS! Thank you very much!

Comment: Update. It works great if I change the "--" to "_" first. Like I did in my initial test. But if I change the code to "--" it no longer works. I don't understand this. Do you have any idea why this would be?

Comment: It also seems to break if there is only one instance of "AA" in colH

Comment: **Point 1**. I misread your question; I saw underscore not hyphen.  It is difficult (not impossible) to place hyphen in a cell because Excel interprets hyphen as the start of a numeric expression. Position the cursor over one of the cells with hyphen and look in the formula bar. You will probably see `'-`. I have changed the code to test for both "-" and "'-". **Point 2**. Sorry, that was careless of me. The line in the middle should be `If RowCrnt <= RowLastAA Then`. That is `<=` not `<`. I have added some comments to explain what is happening.

Comment: **Point 3**. I should have taken more time over my coding because I have spotted another mistake. I seached for "*" meaning anything. The new code searches for "AA" as it should.

Comment: It was still having issues with having hyphens in the columns. Turns out that there was a space in front of the hyphens. I couldn't get it to work with the spaces in there at all. I didn't realize that the hyphens would be so problematic. I had the flexability to be able to remove all the spaces from ColA so I did. But ultimately, your code works very well. Thank you! And thank you for the extra effort with the comments; it really helps me to understand what's going on.

Comment: That may be the best option because there are so many characters that look like hyphen but have a different code. To see this I need you to insert some symbols. Select Insert then Symbol. To insert a symbol click on it so it is white on blue and its name appears bottom right, then click Insert and Close. Insert Hyphen-Minus (middle of the top row) in Cell A1. Insert Soft-Hyphen (row 5 under "(") in Cell A2. Insert Minus Sign in Cell A3. To find Minus Sign, go to the bottom of the symbol table, go up through Arabic and Hebrew (if present) to the Mathematical Operators. Minus Sign is the 5th.

Comment: Cells A1 and A2 will be identical. Cell A3 will have a longer hyphen. Now switch to the VB editor and copy and paste the following into the Immediate window and press Enter: `? Hex(AscW(Range("A1").Value)) & " " & Hex(AscW(Range("A2").Value)) & " " & Hex(AscW(Range("A3").Value))`. The result will be `2D AD 2212` which are the hexadecimal codes for the three characters you inserted.  If you would rather use hyphen, I can show you how to test for all these look alikes.

Comment: One other thing. Why won't my Call or anything else work at the end? I have a couple other calculations to make. Nothing seems to work after this one.

Comment: Have you added these calls to my sub-routine or have to moved my code into a sub-routine of your own?  If so: Replace the two `Exit Sub` statements by `Exit Do`.  `Exit Sub` returns to the caller. `Exit Do` continues from after the `Loop` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim FindAA As Range
Dim ColA As Range
Dim FirstAddress As String

Set FindAA = Sheet1.Columns("H:H").Find("AA", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, _
    xlByRows, xlNext, True)
If FindAA Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
FirstAddress = FindAA.Address
Do
    Set ColA = FindAA.Offset(2, -7)
    While ColA = "--"
        ColA.Rows.Delete
        Set ColA = FindAA.Offset(2, -7)
    Wend
    Set FindAA = Sheet1.Columns("H:H").FindNext(FindAA)
Loop While Not FindAA Is Nothing And FindAA.Address <> FirstAddress

Set FindAA = Nothing
Set ColA = Nothing
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I'm refering to but it's breaking on the line: xlByRows, xlNext, True).FindNext

Comment: Sorry, my Bad.  That was a little left over from testing.  See my edits above.  Also noticed I forgot to check for no instances of 'AA', so a `IF` statement has been added in to account for that.

Comment: Thank you for your effort on this one. Even after switching to another character other than hypens, it's still not working. Tony Dallimore has provided a working solution however. Thanks again!